# Cannot reset face lock programmatically

Tags: java, android, device-admin

I am not sure have I faced bug in android's device admin API or I am using it wrongly.

I need to reset face lock programmatically. My app has nothing except activity with button, which onClick handler resets device password.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View pArg0) {
    DevicePolicyManager admin = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    admin.resetPassword("", 0);
}
```

Everything works fine except case when face lock is enabled. Is this case, lock is not reset and I see following trace:

> 04-03 14:20:15.427: E/JavaBinder(200): *** Uncaught remote exception! 
>   (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.) 04-03
>   14:20:15.427: E/JavaBinder(200): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException:
>   Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires
>   the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want? 04-03
>   14:20:15.427: E/JavaBinder(200):  at
>   android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:847) 04-03
>   14:20:15.427: E/JavaBinder(200):  at
>   com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils.deleteGallery(LockPatternUtils.java:459)
>   04-03 14:20:15.427: E/JavaBinder(200):    at
>   com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils.saveLockPassword(LockPatternUtils.java:605)
>   04-03 14:20:15.427: E/JavaBinder(200):    at
>   com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils.saveLockPassword(LockPatternUtils.java:570)
>   04-03 14:20:15.427: E/JavaBinder(200):    at
>   com.android.server.DevicePolicyManagerService.resetPassword(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:1573)
>   04-03 14:20:15.427: E/JavaBinder(200):    at
>   android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub.onTransact(IDevicePolicyManager.java:428)
>   04-03 14:20:15.427: E/JavaBinder(200):    at
>   android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:338) 04-03 14:20:15.427:
>   E/JavaBinder(200):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

I have checked the source code, it seems that there is attempt to start and activity, however mContext seems to be not activity context.

```
void deleteGallery() {
    if(usingBiometricWeak()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent().setClassName("com.android.facelock",
            "com.android.facelock.SetupFaceLock");
        intent.putExtra("deleteGallery", true);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Has anyone succeeded in resetting face lock, or shall I file a bug?

Comment: Added bug report: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28229